# Не работает .toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот код:

```js
var smiles = $("#smilesChoose");
$("#smilesBtn").click(function () {smiles.toggle(duration  = 600); });
```

```css
.enter_send_mess{
 float: left;
 width: 50px;
 height: 19px;
 margin-top: 2px;
 margin-left: -1px;
 border-top: 1px;
 box-shadow: 0px -2px 1px #9b9b9b;
 opacity: 1;
}

.enter_send_mess:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

#smilesChoose {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
   right: 100px;
   top: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_send_mess">
   <div class="enter_send_mess" id="smilesBtn">Нажми</div>
   <div id="smilesChoose">o:) o.O 3:) <3 :* :-) 8| :/ ;) :'( >:( :( 8) :p :D</div>
</div>
```

Не пойму, почему здесь все работает, а у меня - нет. При клике на кнопку появляется спрятанный блок и при втором клике он пропадает. Только вот у меня на странице он только появляется, а пропадать не хочет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: велика вероятность, что проблема в окружающем коде (html и всякое).  А сама кнопка всё ещё активна после первого срабатывания? На мышу реагирует?

Comment: да, cursor: pointer; и opacity: 0.7; срабатывает нормально

Comment: что самое интересное, если добавить alert("ddd");, то диалог будет появятся при каждом нажатии, но вот пропадать нужный блок не хочет.

Comment: а положите скрипт после кода;)

Comment: не понял, что нужно сделать?

Comment: подключили jquery, ниже html, ниже script с .toggle().

Comment: у меня так и было. Поставил скрипт впереди, все равно не помогло.

Comment: я добавил метод duration (анимацию) и выяснил, что оно у меня не то что бы не закрывается, а оно постоянно появляется.

Comment: если вставить   if ($('#smilesChoose').is(':visible') ) 
   $('#smilesChoose').hide(600);
  else $('#smilesChoose').show(600); тоже самое. Получается, что div для системы спрятан.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56721/discussion-between-kirill-korushkin-and--).

Comment: вы хоть читали про параметры метода `toggle`? он может работать либо без параметров, либо принимать булево значение (показать/скрыть), а вы с какого-то перепугу пишите в параметр `duration = 600`. это выражение, оно выполнится, переменная `duration` станет равной 600,  результатом выражения будет логическое `true`. поэтому ваши блоки всегда будут показываться.

Comment: хотя вобще там и другие варианты есть вызова. но если вы передаете именованный параметр в функцию, они там в `{ }` берутся вроде, и пишутся через  `:` а не присваивание, т.е. в виде объекта

Comment: https://youtu.be/Q4wSGlrAFVk

Comment: я разобрался. всем спасибо